# Firebase FCM, topicSubscription remain the same after the login with another account

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I see that if I subscribe a device to a topic, when I change the account, I continue to receive the notifications for the old account, I think it mean that the notification depend by the device and not by the account. this is a problem if I decide to change account in my device. I use the Cordova FCM plugin

```
FCMPlugin.getToken(
  function(token){
    alert(token);
  },
  function(err){
    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
  }
)

FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('topicExample');

FCMPlugin.unsubscribeFromTopic('topicExample');
```

exist a method to change an account and also the corresponding notification subscription? thanks in advance

Comment: This is interesting. I've been thinking about scenarios like this to see what is the best way to go at it but since it's using topics, it's a bit complicated. There's actually a similar question like this but for device groups [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40140201/4625829)

Comment: i have added my answer, yesterday i make a similar thing that you have write. but the device group is too limited. the problem is this