# handling token changes in notification groups fcm

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Fcm in my App and thats working great.. In My app i am creating notification groups by

```
    $data = array();
    $data["operation"] = "create";
    $data["notification_key_name"] = "gcm";
    $data["registration_ids"] = array("token");
```

and iam successfully received my notificationkey for frequent use... and if the token  changes to another should i remove the tokenid from the notification group  and add the new one everytime ?? or fcm will take care of it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's the developer's responsibility to manage these changes in the Device Group Messaging (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522002/4625829)).

You'll have overwrite/replace the old token with the new one.