# Topic name case sensitivity and `condition` || not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have built spring java service using API logic in firebase cloud messaging.

Here is the URL for sample spring service [https://github.com/petya0111/firebase-spring-service](https://github.com/petq01/firebase-spring-service)

Reproduce: set the request

Run project

```
POST http://localhost:8080/notification/messages

Headers: 
firebase-server-key : [your generated server key]
Body:

{
    "condition": " 'topic' in topics",
    "title": "Hello,Via Multiple Topics",
    "body": "Hello,Via Multiple Topics"
}
```

To send messages to condition you must first create topic

Reproduce: create topic

```
POST https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/{token}/rel/topics/{topic}

headers 
Authorization  : key=[firebase-server-key]

200 OK
```

According to the API's documentation, condition field is defined as case-insensitive.
But in practice, it is actually case sensitive.

I am doing two tests with the same topic name (using upper and lower case chars). The original name of the topic I'm trying to send a message is defined as "Topic". Since the field must be case-insensitive, I am trying to use "topiC" and it should still send the message. Unfortunately, it doesn't. The field is actually case-sensitive and this is a huge problem from my perspective.

My second question:

When a non-existent topic is presented. Exchange with URL https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send doesn't return an error.

My third question on this topic is:
Condition OR '||'

```
 "condition": "  'topicChrome' in topics || 'topicFirefox' in topics "
```

is not working, I have subscribed one token on topic 'topicChrome' and another token on topic 'topicFirefox'.

Comment: Hi. Are you sending the notifications to an Android client app or iOS? Also, could you post a sample payload?

Comment: @AL.  
I've edited my question with sample code and request description. I'm sending notifications to browser devices and also Android devices.

Comment: Cool. For the 2nd question, it's just the usual behavior for FCM topics, regardless if the topic exists or not, it would just return a `messageId`. I'll try to repro the others if I have extra time and get back to you here. Cheers!

Comment: @AL.   I can give you my sample web project and my server key, but I think this must remain private?

Comment: It's fine. I have some stuff here for FCM. And yes, your Server Key must remain secure.

Comment: Hi @petq0111 Sorry wasn't able to get back here for quite some time. I reviewed the docs. The part where it says *"case-insensitive"* is for the `condition` parameter -- i.e. you could use `"'yourTopic' IN TOPICS && 'topic2' IN TOPICS"`. Nothing is mentioned in the docs that the *topic name* itself is case-insensitive though. Even before during the GCM era, I'm pretty sure that topic names have always been case sensitive.

Comment: Nice, thank you, did you tested conditional or operator?  :)

Comment: Yup. It works fine on my end.

Comment: Please, can you explain to me how to reproduce conditional OR operation?

Comment: I pretty much did the same thing as you were. If you're getting a `messageId` in the response, that means the notification was accepted by the FCM server. There might be a different reason as to why you're not receiving the notification on your clients.

Comment: I have subscribed one device for topic 'topic1' and another for 'topic2'. I send with condition field  "condition": "  'topic1' in topics || 'topic2' in topics " The expected behavior is to send to two devices?

Comment: Yup. If the token is subscribed to either of the topics, then yes it should receive the payload.

Comment: I have used this project https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging for front-end javascript app. But I can't understand, why conditional AND is working and OR is not working :(

Comment: That is odd. If you think that this is an unexpected behavior, I suggest reaching out to Firebase support to be able to look into this further. AFAICT and test, this should work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gonna go on ahead and add an answer, details similar to my comments.

> *According to the API's documentation, condition field is defined as case-insensitive. But in practice, it is actually case sensitive.*

The topic name always has been case sensitive. The *case-insensitive* mentioned in the docs refers to the `condition` parameter. In other words, using:

```
"condition": "'topicChrome' IN TOPICS || 'topicFirefox' in topics"
```

(see the upper and lower case words) would be fine.

> *When a non-existent topic is presented. Exchange with URL https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send doesn't return an error*

This is working as expected. It's the developer's responsibility to keep track of which topic exists or doesn't exist (i.e. which ones have subscribers or not), similar to a device group (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522002/4625829)).

For your third question, I've tested the conditions and it was working as expected on my end. I would suggest posting more details (hopefully in a separate question, since multi-questions in a single post isn't really a good practice here), specially showing the response -- is it an error or a success?

Comment: Regarding your last answer. In my case it is not working.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496202/firebase-messaging-conditions-with-multiple-topics-not-working for example code to reproduce the issue

Comment: I just want to confirm that the topics at FCM is case sensitive. news <> NEWS. so keep an eye on it!