# firebase messaging conditions with multiple topics not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the node firebase admin to send messages to Android devices.
All works. Except when I try to send messages to multiple topics.
In the example code below I simply subscribe to 2 topics and directly afterwards i send a notifications to multiple topics in a condition. Nothing arrives on my Phone. When you just send to one topic, the notification arrives successfully. I don't get why it is not working. There is no error response from the firebase admin.
just: 'projects/admob-app-id-xxxx/messages/xxxx'

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: "https://admob-app-id-xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

var registrationTokens = ["xxxxx"];
var topica = "AAA";
var topicb = "BBB";
var data = {};

var message = { 
            condition : "'"+topica+"' in topics || '"+topicb+"' in topics",
            data: {'message':JSON.stringify(data)},
            android: {
                ttl: 36000 * 1000,
                priority: 'normal',
                collapseKey: "test"
            }
        };



        admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topica)
            .then(function(response) {

                admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topicb)
                    .then(function(response) {

                        admin.messaging().send(message, dryRun)
                            .then((response) => {
                            console.log('success', response);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log('error', error);
                    });

                    })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
                });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
        });
```

Comment: You declare `topica` and `topicb` but use `topic1`, `topic2`, and `topic`.  Is the posted code what you are actually running?

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake while pasting the code here. The problem is still there

Comment: What is dryRun set to? Perhaps TRUE?

Comment: @leeJensen No its not. I know now that this is a bug inside the backends of Google messaging. They are aware of it. But somehow they don't fix it.

Comment: I know that bug currently exists on the Web Client, but it is working fine for me with Android. Google support says it is on their list. (and has been for eight months now)

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug with FCM. You can work around it by breaking up your message post into multiple messages.

Instead sending one message.

```
't1' in topics || 't2' in topics || 't3' in topics
```

Send the equivilant three messages.

```
't1' in topics && !('t2' in topics) && !('t3' in topics)
't2' in topics && !('t3' in topics)
't3' in topics
```

Note that the 5 topic limit is still in force.

Comment: Do you have a bug reference? Do you know if this is being worked on?

Comment: I don't remember the original ticket that I referenced, but I don't believe Google has resolved this issue. I found several tickets. All of them closed or open without resolution. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/183 https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/277 https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/104

Comment: I just got a cryptic answer from Firebase support that I can summarize by " this should work but may fail due to having too many users registered". This is obviously wrong as I am just testing with very few users. Waiting for the answer