# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification Key Name

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Firebase Cloud Messaging platform, when you need to create a group, you need send a unique name to it to create a group first. In their documentation it's called `appUser-Chris`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

But I found the name is pretty much useless since all the other API requests are relying on the returned notification key. What's the point of that name, and is it possible to send notifications to a group through that name?(preferably in Node.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What's the point of that name?*

I think the note in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-the-app-server) explains how it can be useful:

> **Note**: `notification_key_name` is not required for adding/removing registration tokens, but including it protects you against accidentally using the incorrect *notification_key*.

Besides that, there was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580404/4625829) that mentioned you can use the `notification_key` using the `notification_key_name`, if you somehow lost it.

<sub>PS: *I'm just not sure how you'll be able to lose the `notification_key`, but keep the `notification_key_name` though.*</sub>

---

> *Is it possible to send notifications to a group through that name?*

Not alone. You still need the `notification_key`. As stated in note above, it acts as a *verifier* that you are using the correct `notification_key`