# Does FCM provide an API of some sort that gives me the Device Group notification key?

Tags: java, python, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have lost few notification key due to which i wont be able to sent the group notification to some set of user. How can i get the notification key by notification key name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to retrieve an existing notification\_key based on a registration id or a notification key name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568632/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-an-existing-notification-key-based-on-a-registration)

Comment: If you still managed to keep the `notification_key_name`, then refer to @camden_kid's answer in the duplicate post.

Answer (score 0):

Make a GET request on this URL:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification?notification_key_name=<your_key_name>
```

Add these to your Headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
project_id:SENDER_ID
```

`Body` should be empty and you shall be seeing something like this:

```
{
    "notification_key": "APA...rc40"
}
```