# Firebase notification_key to send notifications

Tags: android, ios, firebase, playframework, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group) clearly specifies steps to send notification to device groups. It mentions that:

> Create the notification_key, which identifies the device group by
>   mapping a particular group (typically a user) to all of the group's
>   associated registration tokens

Does it mean that `notification_key` is unique for the the device group? Docs do not mention that anywhere explicitly. I wanted to be doubly sure, as add and remove devices to group POST calls return `notification_key` in response making me think that it can change!

At the moment I was persisting `notification_key` once in DB right after group creation and using it for all subsequent requests. Is it the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A device group `notification_key` is expected to be *unique* similar to how registration tokens are.

It is the right approach to store the `notification_key` as soon as possible. What is actually advised is to also [make use of the `notification_key_name`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-the-app-server):

> The `notification_key_name` is a name or identifier (e.g., it can be a username) that is unique to a given group. The `notification_key_name` and `notification_key` are unique to a group of registration tokens.

A *group* doesn't become a new group just because a member is added or removed -- hence it should return the same key.

Comment: So does it also mean that `notification_key` does not change ever? Playing devil's advocate, my concern was say the key 'A' which was unique, changed to a unique key 'B'

Comment: It won't. I think it wouldn't be much of a useful *key* if it constantly changes. Make use of the `notification_key_name`, it would be like a *two-variable-verification* -- key and alias.

Comment: Gotcha thanks! BTW on a separate note do you know if the API mentioned here is still valid (to fetch notification_key from notification_key_name): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568632/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-an-existing-notification-key-based-on-a-registration

Comment: You're welcome. Yup. The InstanceID API is currently available.