# When and what Old FCM Tokens do I need to delete from my backend?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

The way I understand [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) at the moment, I will want to save all FCM tokens a user might have across devices to my backend and send a notification to all of these tokens at once when I want to notify that user about something.

#### Multiple tokens

Until this point, I assumed that each device only has **one active** token, however, reading [this section of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multiple-senders):

> To enable this feature, make sure you have each sender's sender ID. When requesting registration, the client app fetches the token multiple times, each time with a different sender ID in audience field, using the token retrieval method for the given platform

Does this mean that I might need to target *multiple active tokens **per device***?

### Deletion

And now coming to the really important question. A simple solution to the above problem would be to [simply store every token I ever retrieve](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation) in the backend and thus ensuring that my user will always receive the message.

However, what do I do if the user signs out of my app using Firebase Authentication, i.e. a different account is used in the same app on the same device?
I assume that the tokens I sent to my backend for this device will still be active - so now this user will receive notifications from another account because that account was signed in on the device previously.
I do have access to the **current FCM token** and I could delete that from my backend before signing out the old user, but considering the "Multiple tokens" section: *how do I make sure that I can delete all FCM tokens of the old user from my backend*?

### Uniqueness

Additionally, assuming that old tokens are just *dead* for the device (will not trigger notifications anymore) when new ones are generated, can I be sure that this token will never be assigned to another device in the future?

### TL;DR

How can I make sure that I have the correct FCM token(s) for my user stored in my backend and more importantly: *how can I ensure that no tokens of other users are saved for some user in my backend*?

I read through:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40158260/6509751

However, I still do not know how to deal with *multiple tokens*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that I might need to target multiple active tokens per device?

An application has a single active token for each sender ID. It's fairly uncommon to have multiple sender ID, and you'd usually know if if you do. If you're sending from a single back-end, there's usually no need for having multiple sender IDs.